# Why java do not give error on returning an integer while the return type is long or double?

Tags: java, types, casting

```
public double delhi(Integer a)
    {
        return (int)a;
    }
```

In case you do not get it, look at the return type of the method

Comment: Why should it? `int` can implicitly be converted to `double`. You can just write `double d = 5;`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#5.1.2

Comment: In mathematics, the set of integers is included in the set of real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type declared on a method is used to allocate a memory on the stack to store the return value. Here, by declaring return type as `double` compiler will allocate more space (64-bit) than required by the actual return value, an `int` (32-bit). Therefore, there is no loss of data expected on this `(up)conversion`. Therfore, both compiler and runtime, does not complain and it works. Try the opposite, set return type as `int` and return a `long` or `double`. You will get compiler error because there will be potential of data corruption.

Answer (score 1):

Because, an int can fit into a double. its called [**Widening Primitive Conversion**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).

Comment: narrowing would be transforming a double to an int. In this case, it's a **widening** primitive conversion.

Comment: @PremGenError, the link needs updating too.